# Cleaning Excel of #NA values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clean a very large file of #NA Values and 0 (zero values) and I am using the following code. The objective is to reduce the file size by removing these values which are obviously not needed and to improve the file performance. It is a 50 MB file and has become unwieldy

```
Sub cleanna()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


i = 7
Do While i < 1200
j = 1
Do While j < 5100
**If (Cells(i, j) = 0 Or IsError(Cells(i, j))) Then**
   Cells(i, j).Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   j = j + 1
Else
   j = j + 1
End If
Loop
i = i + 1
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

I am getting a Type Mismatch error 13 at some cells and at the line in Bold. Not sure why. Any clues? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Taosique pointed out, the problem arises from the cells with an error being evaluated and checked for 0. Therefore, best make sure it does not have an error and then check if it's zero.

Here's the code I'd use for that:

```
Sub DeleteErrorsAndBlanks()
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    'Speed up the calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rngToCheck = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'Delete all errors
    rngToCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents
    rngToCheck.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).ClearContents

    'Delete all zeros
    For Each rng In rngToCheck
        If rng.Value = 0 Then rng.ClearContents
    Next

    'Reset application
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! If the code (Taosique's or mine) is running really slow, let us know. One can further optimize the execution speed (apart from the `Application....` settings) using arrays.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Maybe it would help if you could tell how it can be made faster using arrays. In another file, I have over 2 billion cells in a sheet which contain some data (count value over the used range, but half of them could be 0s, N/As or ""s). I can employ this technique on that sheet.

Comment: @Peekay: Just wanted to create the code - but then realized that the array approach would only work if it's values only and not formulas. :-( Is this an option, i.e. is the data only consisting of values - or do you need the formulas to stay in place? If the latter, the array attempt won't really help. :-(

Answer (score 1):

That is because `#N/A` will throw an error when compared to Integer. And you don't have to select the cell to clear its contents. Try this:

```
If IsError(Cells(i, j) Then
  Cells(i, j).ClearContents
Else
  If Cells(i, j) = 0 Then
    Cells(i, j).ClearContents
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like the error you pointed was waiting to happen but it failed even before. There was a blank cell and it got stuck there. Lot of crazy things are happening in my workbook and I suspect there is some corruption. I will get back with further comments. I have another file much bigger (100 MB) and I need to do the same. Not sure Excel can handle such big files. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do robustly since VBA evaluates both sides of the `or` even if the first one is `true`. Also it's not sufficient to check `IsError` since there are other errors like #NUM and #VALUE which you should not be catching in your `True` case.

What I would do is build two robust functions and reword your `if` to

```
If isZero(Cells(i, j)) Or isNA(Cells(i, j)) Then
```

The functions are:

```
Private Function isZero(ByVal rng As Excel.Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo error:
    If rng.Value = 0 Then
        isZero = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    'follow through to error is intentional
error:
    isZero = False

End Function


Private Function isNA(ByVal rng As Excel.Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo error:
    If VarType(rng.Value) = vbError Then
        If rng.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
            isNA = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    'follow through to error is intentional
error:
    isNA = False

End Function
```

Note the `xlErrNA` value which isolates the error type to #N/A.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Surely I will need more help.